# Connecting Unity with SQL server

Tags: android, sql, unity-game-engine

He everyone I have problem with connect to sql server in android type phone i will summit code that code is working in `windows application` but when i build to `android` its give error I need and hope to help me for solve this issue thank u

This is Error when I build to android apk:

[image]

and this is code the which is working in windowns app:

```
#pragma strict
import System;
import System.Data;
import System.Data.SqlClient;
var dbcon : IDbConnection;
var connectionString : String;

function Start () {
    connectionString = "Server=dbdatabase.mssql.somee.com; Database=dbdatabase;User ID=dbdatabase_SQLLogin_1; Password=1j8uc1yyja"; 
}

function Update () {
}

var user :String="";
var pas :String="";
function OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(150, 130, 100, 100), "Name :");
    GUI.Label(new Rect(150, 160, 120, 120), "Pass :");
    user = GUI.TextField(new Rect(200, 130, 100, 20), user);
    pas=GUI.TextField(new Rect(200,160,100,20),pas);

    if (GUI.Button(Rect(200,190,100,50),"Login"))
    {
        dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        dbcon.Open();
        var dbcmd : IDbCommand = dbcon.CreateCommand();
        var cmdSql : String = "SELECT name FROM setting WHERE name='"+user+"' and pass='"+pas+"'";     
        dbcmd.CommandText = cmdSql;  
        var reader : IDataReader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader .Read()) {
            var nm : String = reader ["name"].ToString();
           print ("OK "+nm);
        }

        reader .Close();
        reader = null;
        dbcon.Close();
        dbcon = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: See the error message.

Comment: The error message IS pretty self explaining.

Comment: please  some one can help me about this issue  ...

Comment: i do that but still error is available